# Create a session mechanism without cookies

Tags: c#, asp.net, session-state, cookieless

I'm currently working with a device that renders xml's views served by an IIS server. Unfortunately the device doesn't support either cookies or redirects which invalidates the usage of both the regular asp.net sessions or cookieless sessions.

The data exceeds the size permitted by url query string so that isn't an option either.

What I wanted to do is to have some kind of custom session mechanism where I can explicitly tell the session ID (the Id could be the mac address of the device that is passed in the url querystring).

I could use an sql database but I wanted to avoid that.

Any ideas?

EDIT:

I just got informed that the solution is going to run on a load balancer so it seems that I'm really going to the SQL solution. Thanks for the replies which are both valid but it seems that I don't have much of a choice in this...

Answer (score 3):

All you need is a key unique to the user. If you have access to a Mac address then use that. I would probably opt for a GUID and pass that round in the query string though.

Server side you can either go for the database approach (or any form of file storage, but DB with be optimised for query performance), or store the information in memory. Create a static dictionary type class that associates data against each "unique key". Then you can easily query the data.

The more difficult part comes when you need to work out when a session expires. If you take the database approach you could write a windows service to query a "last updated session" flag and delete the session if it expires past a given time. This would probably be alot more difficult to manage if you opt for the "in memory" approach.

Another disadvantage of the "in memory" option is that you need to be careful about storing too much information and draining the available memory. This is the primary reason I would go for database storage

Answer (score 1):

Unless you want to make every interaction a POST, where you pass the session data along each time the user clicks on a link, you will have to store the state somewhere (such as a database), and look it up with a lightweight ID (like the mac address you described).

Of course, it doesn't have to be a SQL database, you can look at other storage mechanisms like  [redis](http://redis.io/).